# How to see connection attempts rejected by firewall in real time?

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, nfs

I am struggling to create an NFS mount from my Mac to a Ubuntu server (the mount works if I do it locally on the server to itself, so I'm confident the issue is network related), and I need to have some visibility on incoming traffic to the server - **specifically if any connections are being dropped or rejected due to firewall rules I may not be aware of**.

Any ideas how I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the Ubuntu server iptables firewall, there's a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10150/is-there-a-way-to-find-which-iptables-rule-was-responsible-for-dropping-a-packet).

It suggests you add a TRACE or use `iptables -L -v -n | less` to have a better insight into existing rules.

To see the log updated in real time you would then `tail -F /var/log/kern.log` unless you specified a different log file for your firewall.

Comment: Yes! The realtime trace using 'tail' has worked for me. Nice one ;-)