# How to identify which iptables rule has rejected specific connection (from log output)?

Tags: iptables, ufw

I have got a log readout showing connection attempts being rejected by iptables rule(s) (from the solution to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1182321/how-to-see-connection-attempts-rejected-by-firewall-in-real-time)), shown below:

```
Feb 24 11:19:24 devmachine kernel: [17771118.615519] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth2 OUT= MAC=00:1a:4b:b0:27:c8:c0:ea:e4:0e:b7:2c:08:00 SRC=172.x.x.x DST=192.x.x.x LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=13372 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61722 DPT=32869 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

My question is: How do I use this to identify the specific rule that blocked access (so I can alter or remove that rule)?